# (Algolia) The keyword "any " cannot be searched when it comes at the beginning of queries

Tags: magento, algolia

I’m facing a problem about search product in algolia from magento. I have some products have brand name is Any DI. The problem is, If I search “any di” query → There’s no results about “Any di” (Only “di” query is searchable), If I search “any-di” or “any_di” or “di any” → It works.
I’m assuming that "any " is a special keyword in algolia which can not use as a query parameter. Does any know why and how to resolve it.
Thanks so much

I would like "any di" to be searchable.